# Create Text Boxes on each selection of dynamically dropdown with selected value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am dynamically adding table rows. Each row has input fields, as well as, drop down fields which is coming dynamically.
When I select value from dropdown I want to add text boxes of selected value through id which is selected.I want to perform this on each selection of dropdown in dynamically added row .
How can I add & remove text boxes on each selection of dropdown?

Comment: What about providing relevant code in question?!

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have this:

```
<tr>
  <td>
   <select class='someclass' id='select20'>
      <option value='a'>A</option>
      <option value='b'>B</option>

   </select>
   <div id='txtbox_container20' class='cont-class'></div>
  </td>
</tr>

<script>
  $(document).read(function(){
   $(".someclass").change(function(){
   $(this).next("div.cont-class").html("<input type='text' value='anything'/>");
});
});
</script>
```

The above script works for all of your `<select>` dynamically. Just consider two points:

1- make you script (php or js I don't know) to make a div with a fixed className after each `select` tag.

2- this script works with classes and not IDs.

3- Include jQuery before this script since it uses jQuery.

Comment: if it worked out then please accept it as an answer.